# Why does the function to close logging handlers not run when I expect?

Tags: python, logging

Can anyone explain why the `close_handlers` function does not run across every handler that is an instance of `MyHandler`? When I run the script below, the first `close_handlers` call in `thing_1`'s `finally` block only seems to close 1 of the 2 handlers added to the logger in `set_up_logging`.

When it gets to the second `close_handlers` call, it appears that this closes 3 handlers, and by this time, the handler that was 'missed' the first time round has appended all 4 log statements to its buffer. I'd expect all handlers to flush for `thing_1` and be removed, and this to be replicated in `thing_2` but this is clearly not happening.

The use case is gathering logs for particular function calls to send to a separate messaging service, and I'd like all the logs to be gathered for each function call and sent as a formatted group. I'm finding this behavior on the formatted messages I'm sending (i.e. duplicated, overlapping messages being sent because handlers aren't closing when they're meant to). I'm closing and re-adding handlers each time as I need info about the current function call to format the title of each message:

```
import logging
from logging.handlers import BufferingHandler

_logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)


class MyHandler(BufferingHandler):

    def __init__(self, capacity: int):
        super().__init__(capacity)

    def flush(self):
        print(self.buffer)
        super().flush()


def set_up_logging():
    logging.basicConfig()
    root_logger = logging.getLogger()
    root_logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    root_logger.addHandler(MyHandler(10))
    root_logger.addHandler(MyHandler(5))


def close_handlers():
    for handler in logging.getLogger().handlers:
        if isinstance(handler, MyHandler):
            logging.getLogger().removeHandler(handler)
            handler.close()


def thing_1():
    try:
        set_up_logging()
        _logger.info("hi")
        _logger.error("something went wrong")
    finally:
        print(len(logging.getLogger().handlers))
        close_handlers()


def thing_2():
    try:
        set_up_logging()
        _logger.info("hi again")
        _logger.error("something else went wrong")
    finally:
        print(len(logging.getLogger().handlers))
        close_handlers()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    thing_1()
    thing_2()
```

Comment: For the same reason `x = [1,2]; for i in x: x.remove(i)` only removes one item: you are removing items from the list of handlers while you are iterating over the same list.

Comment: Of course it is. Brain fart. Thanks.

Comment: It's not immediately obvious because the fact that you are modifying `logging.getLogger().handlers` is encapsulated in the call to `logging.getLoggers().removeHandler`.